# Get user's timezone for Gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

How to get the user's timezone in the appscript for Gmail add-on. I don't want the script's timezone but user's. 
I just need to display some history. So if I can convert UTC to user's timezone in client-side, it is also fine.

`Session.getScriptTimeZone()` gives the script's timezone, not the user's.

Is there a way to get the timezone of the user or show the time according to the user's computer timezone?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `toLocaleDateString`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

The sample add-on uses this (https://github.com/googlecodelabs/gmail-add-ons/blob/f33d04657b1dd27b5137c3b4e2d73ccce99d9615/Step-6/Helpers.js#L43)

Answer (score -1):

1. `Session.getScriptTimeZone();` gets the user's timezone that is set on their Gmail account. If the user wants to change their timezone, they have to change it through Google Calendar [(how to change timezone)](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-correct-your-gmail-time-zone-1172121).
2. If you want to get the timezone that reflects the user's computer's settings, here is a small script:

   ```js
   function getTimeZone(){
       var now = new Date().toString();
       var timeZone = now.replace(/.*[(](.*)[)].*/,'$1');//extracts timezone string
       return timeZone;
   }
   ```
3. Additionally, you can add Moment.js to your Apps Script project 
   and utilize the functions they already built: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I need to show the time according to the user's Gmail timezone or PC timezone. Session.getScriptTimeZone will not give the user's timezone but the script's. Can you refer a document which supports your point?